# if cells have equal value in same column

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a formula for a countback feature in google sheets if possible. 
I have a list of competitors race times (W4:W93) and have them ranked (X4:X93) and but if I get Identical times it throws out another formula for overall results.

my sticking point is I can't work out how to compare if the value in any cell is equal to another cell in the same column excluding itself, I have found plenty of info on equal values but not if they are in the same column.
any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I note that this question has been voted down with no explanatory comments. The question is not on hold, it is not closed because it might be duplicate, or answered elsewhere, and no one has edited the question to provide greater clarity. That seems a pretty rough call to me.

---

In any event, I'm pretty sure that I've been in the situation described by the OP many times and I've had to be creative about finding and removing duplicate values. There are several ways to find/highlight/manipulate duplicate values, though Google doesn't seem to have as many options as Excel. One method is to use conditional formatting and this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrwFQqxzQn8) explains it very well.

But I will use one of my all-time absolute favourite formulae to find duplicates. In addition, since the OP is working  with 90 competitors, finding the duplicates is only the task, the OP also needs to arrange them in a way that assists analysis.

This [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rT77TpD2N-E3nSJXoUPGGa8mqqc2csWHU7GVpB9X-ik/edit?usp=sharing) shows the workings:

First, create a header, say, "Equal Rank" for column Y (the first column after "Ranking") and insert this formula in cell Y4:

```
=if(countif($W:$W,W4)=1,"Unique","Duplicate")
```

The formula has two components.

1. COUNTIF
2. IF statement

The COUNTIF looks at cell W4 (the race time) in the first row of results. The count range is Column W; the range could just as easily be limited to actual data but the key is that it is expressed as an "absolute" (note the $ signs in the range).The formula counts how many times the value in cell W4 appears in the range.

The IF statement evaluates the result of the COUNTIF. If the result appears only once, then the cell value is "Unique". If the value appears more than once, then it is a "Duplicate" value.

The OP has 90 competitors and will need to drill down to the duplicate results quickly. So, I suggest a variation of the classic formula, this:

```
=if(countif($W$4:$W$93,W4)=1,"",X4)
```

The formula still consists of two components, but if the result is unique, then no value is entered; conversely if the result is a duplicate, then the existing "Rank" (cell X4) is returned. BTW, this version shows how the range address would look if you evaluated only the populated range.

Now, sort the range A3:Y93 (I am assuming there is relevant data in columns A-V). FWIW, I inserted a column "Sequence" and gave it a numeric sequence so that once the "Equal Ranks" had been fixed, I could resort on the "Sequence" column to return the data to the original sort order - the OP may or may not need this.

To aggregate the duplicate values:
Select the Range> right-click > Sort range > "Data has Header Row" = checked> 'Sort by' "Equal Rank", Sort order: "A->Z".

From here, Race Times could be adjusted by a tenth, or hundredth, of a second to avoid duplicate times.

Once this is complete, select the full range again, and resort. In my case I used my "Sequence" column to return the data to the original sort order.

Comment: That worked perfect thank you, I was not far off in the end with trying to work it out but hadn't quite nailed it. Also, I thank you for your kind words to start.

Comment: is there a way to incorporate an isblank or to ignore blanks, I keep getting a "Formula parse error."  or i tried this "=if(isblank(W11),"",if(countif($W$4:$W$93,W11)=1,"","Countback Needed"))" however I get the blank cell coming up with Countback Needed.

Comment: Dunno. I can't see why your formula doesn't work. Check the spreadsheet, I've added a "Countback Needed?" column using that same formula.